# Tengo un problema de código en c++ . A la hora de ejecutar el programa, se me queda trabado en un bucle

Tags: c++, bucles

Estoy haciendo un programa que simula de cierta manera al juego de black jack y eh estado avanzando hasta que hoy de tarde me encontré con este error y no lo eh podido solucionar.

no cite todo el código porque la parte de arriba seria donde se logean los jugadores y les pregunta nombre, saldo, etc...

**El problema del bucle surge a la hora de ejecutar el Segundo switch el cual tiene como variable ops2. que esta adentro del case ('J') del primer switch (ops).**
El programa se me queda tipo en bucle y no deja hacer nada. No da opciones, y no deja salir del switch, ni continuar.

Si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar el error de porque se me queda trabado ahí se lo agradecería muchísimo.
Saludos!

````
    do { 
        cout << "(J)ugar \n";
        cout << "(V)er apuestas \n";
        cout << "(S)alir \n";
        cin >> ops;

    switch (ops) {

            case ('j'): case ('J'): 
                if (saldo2 >= 50 && saldo1 >=50) {
                int apuesta1, apuesta2;
                cout << "  Apuesta minima 50 \n " << player1 << " Ingrese el numero de su apuesta: ";
                cin >> apuesta1;
                while (apuesta1 < 50 || apuesta1 > saldo1) {
                cout << "Apuesta invalida por favor ingrese de nuevo su apuesta: " ;
                cin >> apuesta1;
                }
                saldo1 = saldo1 - apuesta1;
                cout << "Apuesta minima 50 \n " << player2 << " Ingrese el numero de su apuesta: ";
                cin >> apuesta2;
                while (apuesta2 < 50 || apuesta2 > saldo2) {
                cout << "Apuesta invalida por favor ingrese de nuevo su apuesta: " ;
                cin >> apuesta2;
                }
                saldo2 = saldo2 - apuesta2;
                cout << player1 << " Saco la carta: \n";
                srand (time(NULL)); //Tuve que sacar el srand de la funcion "Baraja" porque me daba el mismo numero a ambos jugadores
                baraja(&n);
                imagen_carta (n);
                aux1=n;
            {   
                cout << player2 << " Saco la carta: \n";
                baraja(&n);
                imagen_carta (n);
                aux2=n;  
            }  
                char ops2;
                cout << "¿" << player1 << " ¿Quieres otra carta? \n Responde J si quieres otra o T si no quieres otra carta ";
                cout << "(J)ugar";
                cout << "(T)erminar \n";
                cin >> ops2;
                switch (ops2) {  
                    case ('J'): case ('j'):
                        cout << player1 << " Saco la carta: \n";
                        {
                        baraja(&n);
                        imagen_carta (n);
                        aux1 = aux1 + n;
                        cout << player1 << " Lleva actualmente: " << aux1;
                        }
                    break;

                    case ('T'): case ('t'):
                        cout << "quedas con: " << aux1;
                    break;   
                        default: cout << "fuera de rango";   
                        }
                while (ops2 != 'T' && ops2 != 't');
}
            else { cout << "Uno de los jugadores no tiene saldo suficiente \n";
            } 
        break;

            case ('v'): case ('V'): 
                cout << "Nombre: "<<player1<< "\n Saldo actual: "<< saldo1 << "\n";
                cout << "Nombre: "<<player2<< "\n Saldo actual: "<< saldo2 << "\n"; 
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case ('s'): case ('S'):
                cout << "Chau :D \n"; 
            break;
            default: cout << "Fuera de Rango";
       }
    }
    while (ops != 's' && ops != 'S');

}  // ------------------------  Cierro main  ----------------------


void imagen_carta(int n) {
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){      // dibujar la i-esima fila
        if (i==1||i==7){
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            cout <<".";
            cout <<"\n";
        }
        else{
            if(i==4){
                for (int b = 1; b <= 2; b++){
                cout << ".";    
                if(b<2){
                    for(int j=1;j<=1 ;j++){
                    cout << "   " << n <<"   ";
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    cout << "\n";
                }

                }
            }
            else    
            {
                for (int b = 1; b <= 2; b++){
                cout << ".";    
                if(b<2){
                    for(int j=1;j<=1 ;j++){
                    cout << "   ";
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    cout << "\n";
                }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void baraja (int *n) {  // Genera un numero random entre el 1 y el 9 
        *n = (rand() % 9) + 1;
} ```
````

Comment: con la tabulación tan mala que tiene tu código cuesta un montón saber dónde empieza y dónde acaba cada ámbito... ¿Podrías mejorar la tabulación e indicar exactamente dónde se queda pillado el juego?

Comment: "*se me queda trabado en un bucle*" ¿En cuál? ¡Tienes varios bucles en tu código!

Comment: Listo ahí tabule un poco mas el código. y añadí mejor información

Answer (score 0):

Al inicio de la condicion `J`, validas las variables `saldo1` y `saldo2` que san >= que 50, pero luego haces calculos con ellas, reduciendo su valor.

Esto puede estar provocando que la segunda condition `|| apuesta2 > saldo2` siempre sea verdadera no importando si `apuesta2 >= 50`, si `saldo2 < 50`.